# how do I load a list of variables from dot mat file

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a big `test.mat` file, and I only wanted to load in several variables from it with variable names stored as `varnames = {'var1','var10','var100'}`. How would I transform `varnames` to be used in `load`?

Manually writing `load('test.mat', 'var1','var10','var100')` is not a good option since `varnames` could be long and dynamically generated. I also make it explicitly that individual variable names could have different lengths that `char(varnames` will fail.

`load('test.mat', varnames)` or `load('test.mat', char(varnames))` or several other variants I tried do not work.
thanks.

Comment: Like this: `load('test.mat', varnames{:});`